# I can't to add template to EasyAdmin CollectionField

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I try to customize CollectionField for EasyAdmin 4.0.3.

I created EntityCrudController

```
class EntityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Entity::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return Crud::new()
            ->setDefaultSort(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
    }

    public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
    {
        return $filters
            ...
        ;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            ...,
            CollectionField::new('history', 'History')
                ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/history.html.twig')
                ->setDisabled(true)
                ->allowAdd(false)
                ->allowDelete(false),
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see I added "admin/field/history.html.twig" to CollectionField.

After I created "templates/admin/field/history.html.twig" just with simple content for example "11111" and I expect to see this instead of field content (template will be filled later). "templates" already contains another templates and they are works correctly.

But anyway I see built-in template with accordion.

Debug shows that it uses "vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/views/crud/form_theme.html.twig" for generating collection content in block "collection_widget".

{{ dump() }} shows that form of the field contains templatePath = "admin/field/history.html.twig" - this is my path

How can I change this template to custom?

Comment: The `setTemplatePath()` method only applies to fields displayed on the `index` and `detail` pages. To customize fields in the `new` and `edit` pages you should use template fragments and a combination of `addFormTheme()` and `setFormThemes()` methods: https://symfony.com/doc/current/EasyAdminBundle/design.html#fields-and-actions-templates